# Extracting elements from the nd array and storing them into different vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an ndimenstional array of shape `1x17x3` whose output looks as follows

```
[[[x1 y1 z1]
  [x2 y2 z2]
  [x3 y3 z3]
  [x17 y17 z17]]]
```

I want to extract the first two elements in a 1D vector as follows

```
vec1 = [x1,y1,x2,y2, ....... x17,y17]
vec20 [z1,z2,z3..............z17]
```

I tried to flatten the whole array and extract the elements but ,  I am not sure thats the right way to work .

```
import numpy as np
test = np.random.rand(1,17,3)
print(test)
rev_mat = test.flatten()
print(rev_mat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let x denote your array of shape 1x17x3.

```
vec1 = np.empty(x.shape[1] * 2)
vec1[0::2] = x[:,:,0]
vec1[1::2] = x[:,:,1]

vec20 = x[:,:,2].squeeze()
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

With a 2d array:

```
In [42]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)                                                              
In [43]: arr                                                                                           
Out[43]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

we can get the first 2 columns with:

```
In [44]: arr[:,:2]                                                                                     
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

and make that 1d with `ravel`

```
In [45]: arr[:,:2].ravel()                                                                             
Out[45]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  6,  7,  9, 10])
```

third column:

```
In [46]: arr[:,2]                                                                                      
Out[46]: array([ 2,  5,  8, 11])
```

You have 3d, but the first dimension is 1, so you can just 'index' it a way:

```
In [47]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(1,4,3)                                                            
In [48]: arr                                                                                           
Out[48]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
In [49]: arr[0,:,:2].ravel()                                                                           
Out[49]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  6,  7,  9, 10])
```